# SVN branch by feature for beginners

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I work with a PL/SQL team that is used to version control with SourceSafe which is based on a lock per file. One user "owns" the file. When delivering new code, someone consolidate manually all the changes, and the consolidation pack is deployed on the staging environment. If something is broken, they just remove the broken code from the consolidation pack and then staging again. If everything is OK, they deploy the consolidation pack in production.

Now they have to code in Java, and use SVN. This is a big change. We setup a strategy for development and deployment but we are not 100% satisfied.

Branches:

- trunk: The code is stable and deployed in production.
- feature: Each feature is developed in a specific branch created from trunk.
- maintenance: This branch is used to fix production bug, it was created from trunk just after deployment in production. We just have to handle N-1 version.

Before deploying we want to test the new feature and the maintenance bugfixes into a staging environment. Our idea is to merge the maintenance and feature branches we want to test into trunk. Deploy trunk in the staging environment.

**Case 1: New feature needs bugfix**

- Fix is done in the feature branch
- When fixed, feature branch is merged into trunk

*Q: What if the feature is not working because of a maintenance bugfix? Should the feature fix be done in trunk?*

**Case 2: New feature is not production ready, we can't release it in the short term**

- Since the feature has been merged into trunk, we have to revert that branch from.

*Should we revert all the merges since the latest production release, and remerge only the wanted branches?*

**Case 3: The staging is lasting 2 weeks but bugfix production still needs to be commited**

- The maintenance branch has been merged into trunk.

*On which branch should we commit the bugfix during the staging period. If we commit them on the maintenance branch, we might lose these changes because when staging is done, trunk will be in production, and a new maintenance branch will be created from that trunk. So the new maintenance branch will miss the commits from the old maintenance branch done during the staging period.*

As you can see, a lot of question unanswered, and a complex strategy with a lot of merge (time consuming and error-prone). From the blogs I read on the subject, I think our branches setup is faily common though. We are open to any modification, the goal is to have a simple and understandable strategy.

Comment: Source Safe: The very worst source code management system ever written.  Do yourself a favor and get out of it right away.  Trunk is just a special branch name.  You don't have to merge to trunk to use Subversion properly.  Have a look at Scott Ambler's thoughts on agile databases: http://www.agiledata.org/

Comment: This seems way too broad and/or too opinion-based to be a good fit for SO.

Comment: This would all work better with Git thanks to its better merging capabilities. But you probably knew that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems way too broad and/or too opinion-based to be a good fit for SO, but...

**Case 1:**

If you don't merge bigfixes from MAINT back to "branches-for-work" - you done branching|merging bad. I.e. for previously merged to trunk feature-branch you have (from my POV):

- write bugfix in feature-branch, merge new range (auttomatically detected for not-so-ancient SVN) into trunk, which was previously already synced with maintenance. "if the feature is not working because of a maintenance bugfix" you have to *add new bugfix in feature-branch* for "getting maintenance compability" and merge again

But **beware**: cyclic merges in SVN (even freshest) can produce strange and bad results with Tree Conflicts at unpredictable (so-so) points

> Should the feature fix be done in trunk?

This is more question of local policy, but for "Stable trunk" I prefer to see trunk with only mergesets from different branches in it (easier discoverable history)

**Case 2:**

In case of mergesets-only (to some degreee, see below) trunk, you have to reverse merge single mergeset in trunk, with not-ready-to production feature merged to trunk. **Note**: in order to return feature back, you have not re-merge feature-branch, you have to reverse merge revision, which (in turn) reverse merge feature from trunk

**Case 3**

Yes, MAINT with hotfixes in it **must be merged** into STAGING (trunk), and trunk re-tested as for any other merges